# Why are vortices stable?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, stability, vortex

Vortices persist over time, but change their shape.

I am used to a structure that persists being “stable” as in it is robust against small perturbations.

How can one define stability of a Vortex? For example how could one prove that the bathtub vortex is stable? What does it even mean for it to be stable if it’s shape changes?

Comment: It is worth specifying that you are talking about vortices in liquid (or specifically in water) rather than those in atmosphere, superconductor or some other situation.

Comment: @RogerVadim, Good point. I am talking generally about vortices in fluid where fluid is used in the broader sense of the word. I am being general because in a wide variety of situations vortex's seem to persist in fluids, and from an outside perspective I would expect a general result or lens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can define the stability of a vortex by perturbing it in some way and seeing if that perturbation grows or decays.

For an initially circular vortex ring, we could add a sinusoidal perturbation to its shape and see if the amplitude of the sinusoid grows. [It has been shown](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1973.0029) that vortex rings are unstable to such a sinusoidal perturbation.

For the bathtub vortex you ask about, it is itself the result of an instability of the flow draining down a plug. Water draining from a bath tub could drain without any swirl or vortex, the flow velocity could be entirely radial towards the plughole. Indeed, for low enough $(\lessapprox50)$ Reynolds numbers that is what happens.

However, for higher Reynolds numbers the base flow is unstable to a swirl perturbation and the flow starts to rotate faster and faster, forming the familiar bathtub vortex. More detail can be found in [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.90.041002).

Comment: _We can define the stability of a vortex by perturbing it in some way and seeing if that perturbation grows or decays._ But what if the perturbation grows but does not lessen the spinning motion. For example, if I perturbed a tornado, and the perturbation caused the tornado to change direction, the perturbation is growing, but I still think of the tornado as stable, since the concentrated vorticity is preserved.

Answer (score 2):

The basic ingredient of stability is is [Kelvin's circulation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin%27s_circulation_theorem) which says that for inviscid flow $\Gamma=\oint_\gamma {\bf v}\cdot d{\bf r}$ is a constant when the contour $\gamma$ is advected with the flow.

Comment: This makes sense. And I have seen this result. But it does not seem to say anything about the stability against small perturbations. Unless I am misunderstanding.

Comment: @jrudd This is a non-perturbative argument, it is ultimately based on topology.